# iOS iBeacon location

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

is there a way to show the beacon direction as an arrow point the direction to the beacon? I know it is possible to change the color according to the proximity of the beacon but what I need is a direction to find the beacon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this just with one beacon as all you have is the received signal strength (RSSI). The [Determining Location Using Bluetooth Beacons](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/bluetoothleposition) article explains more and references a paper that shows a workaround that might help when using just one beacon.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, **you cannot get direction to a Bluetooth beacon.  A Bluetooth receiver on a mobile phone is omni-directional.**  It works much like an old-fashioned AM radio.  You can get some idea how far away a radio station is by how much static you hear, but there is no way to know which way the transmitter is by standing still and listening.

The paper that @Simon-Judge mentions in his answer basically suggests it could be possible to figure out roughly which way the transmitter is by spinning around in place and measuring signal.  To take the AM radio analogy, this is similar to pointing the antenna in each direction in 180 degrees to see where it picks up the signal best.  While this might work with some degree of success, it certainly isn't going to plot an arrow on the screen for the direction of the beacon.

Comment: Thanks, David I read the paper and was wondering if could be more precise.